# Constructor and Method overloading

Tags: c#, overloading

is there any way to do this kind of overloading...

```
public SampleConstructor() : this (null, null) { }
public SampleConstructor(Object a, Object b) { }
```

...but in method? I mean the way it use `:` to call its overload.

So, if it's possible, I don't wanna use this way of calling method overloads :

```
public void SampleMethod() { SampleMethod(null) }
public void SampleMethod(Object a) { }
```

...and using the construction way to call its overload.

P.S.

I know, and have tried that...

```
public void SampleMethod() : this (null) { }
public void SampleMethod(Object a) { }
```

...doesn't work.

So, is there any way to make the `:` overloading works on method? Since it's simpler that way, rather than calling the overload from the inside. (Or, maybe, it's not even possible?)

Comment: `public void SampleMethod() : this (null) { }` this will never work (as `this` is your Class), you best bet will be `public void SampleMethod() : this.SampleMethod (null) { }` (not exist as well)

Comment: I think the short answer is "no". Is there a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I need to make sure. There is no particular problem i'm trying to solve, just a matter of code readability. Please write it in the answer and i'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use default values:

`public void SampleMethod(Object a = null) { }`

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I do try to avoid default values. They tend to make things more complicated and harder to maintain, vs overloading.

Comment: @JonB But don't they just compile into overloaded methods?

Comment: Not sure. But they make the source code less readable, and can cause bugs if you're not careful.

Comment: @JonB And there we disagree, but such is the way with opinions.

Comment: Indeed! And it's not like I haven't used them, either :)

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is wrong, but this is off topic, sorry.